# Explicit Descriptions of $q-SO(2)$, and $q-Sp(2)$?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

When ever I hear noncommutative geometers talking about quantum groups, it is usually $q-SU(2)$ that they are discussing. As a result there are many good and explicit generator and relation presentations of this Hopf algebra. For an easy example take this other M.O. [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10581/kontsevich-and-geometric-quantization-and-the-podles-sphere). I am curious to see what the simple examples of the other quantum groups series are. More specifically, could anyone give me a generator and relation description of the Hopf algebras 
$$
q-SO(2), ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ q-Sp(2)?
$$
I know that somehow these are derivable from the some quantized enveloping algebra dual quantum groups, but that's a little too difficult for a ''classical'' geometer like me!

Comment: Have you looked in any books?  You should be able to find these in most, if not all, introductory quantum groups books.  Off the top of my head, I would check Chapter 9 of the book Quantum Groups and Their Representations, by Klimyk and Schmudgen.

Comment: Sometimes $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can serve the role of a quantum $U(1)$ in that it has a quasitriangular structure and is a subalgebra of $U_q SU(2)$ for $q$ the right root of unity. Majid's book has details about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, $SO(2)\approx U(1)$ has no nontrivial quantum deformation, but $SO(3)$ does; this is explicitly constructed in:

[Symmetries of quantum spaces. Subgroups and quotient spaces of quantum SU(2) and SO(3) groups](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/9402069), P. Podles (1994)

[Quantum SO(3) groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0398), P.M. Soltan (2008)

For *q-Sp(2)*, see Section 3.2 of

[Noncommutative families of instantons](http://www.math.ru.nl/~waltervs/laparesuIMRN.pdf), G. Landi et al. (2008).

More general references on quantum classical groups:

[Quantum deformation of classical groups](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=28&iss=1&rank=5), T. Hayashi (1992)

[Quantum symmetric spaces and related q-orthogonal polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9503225), M. Noumi and T. Sugitani (1995)

[Orthogonal and symplectic quantum matrix algebras and Cayley-Hamilton theorem for them](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511618), O. Ogievetsky and P. Pyatov (2005)